# Lifetime Color Change Material + Time Remapping = Problem (Cycles Animation)

Tags: rendering, animation, materials, node-editor, frame-rate

I am posting because I've been working on a problem all day and I can' t find the right solution anywhere. I'm going crazy. :P

---

**My situation:**

- I have an animated scene in 24 fps
- I want to release the final render
  with animation in 120fps
- The scene contains Particles, and an
  important element is that they change their color over time. Example Video:
  https://youtu.be/QvATUlmguyk
  [image]
- I've tried many different ways, but each one of them ruins the final effect in some aspects.

---

**A partial solution to the problem I managed to come up with:**

- The best way I could find it was to change FPS, Time Remapping and End Frame. Below is an example of how I changed it.:
  [image]
- After the implementation of the above change, all animations work correctly.
- However, there is a problem with Particles Material. Which, due to the change of time completely fails to work. During rendering it is completely white.
- Material nodes:

[image]

- I thought that to solve the problem it is enough to divide Age into 5 and multiply LifteTime x5 but unfortunately it does not solve it. Below you can find nodes that don't work.
  [image]

---

It seems to me that the solution should be rather mathematically simple, but unfortunately I do not understand it at all. HELP! :(